# Openssl speed benchmark test

Tags: performance, testing, openssl

Recently I need to test openssl suite performance on my machine. I ran speed to get some performance numbers. However I wanted specific performance such as encrytion time and decrytion time but the data I got is in the form of

```
Doing aes-128 cbc for 3s on 16 size blocks: 24115540 aes-128 cbc's in 3.00s
```

I checked speed.c file and it was

```
if (doit[D_CBC_128_AES])
        {
        for (j=0; j<SIZE_NUM; j++)
            {
                        print_message(names[D_CBC_128_AES],c[D_CBC_128_AES][j],lengths[j]);
            Time_F(START);
            for (count=0,run=1; COND(c[D_CBC_128_AES][j]); count++)
                AES_cbc_encrypt(buf,buf,
                    (unsigned long)lengths[j],&aes_ks1,
                    iv,AES_ENCRYPT);// :O only encryption
            d=Time_F(STOP);
                        print_result(D_CBC_128_AES,j,count,d);//xxxxx

            }
        }
```

So it is only doing encryption, not decryption.

Why is it so?
How can I get encryption time, and decryption time of algorithms and their modes? 
Do I have to write code myself for all algorithms?
How can I get cpu cycles used in a particular algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

AES encryption and decryption times are about the same.

Yes, you will need to write your own tests because the times are affected by the processor type, processor speed and implementation. I have seen differences of 1000 times in speed on the same device with different implementations.